# Como formatar campo Data em Formulário Ionic / Angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic

Tenho um campo data num formulário que está assim:

```
<label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
            <span class="input-label">Validade da Oferta</span>
            <input type="date" ng-model="product.cadastra_oferta_validade_oferta" placeholder="Validade da Oferta" />               

        </label>
```

Mas ele não armazena em meu PHP, porque o formato de data no banco de dados é diferente. Alguma dica de como resolver este problema? Segue meu PHP:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

    //formulário

    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $objData = json_decode($data);

    // TRANSFORMA OS DADOS

    $cod_categoria_com = $_GET['cod_categoria_com'];
    $titulo_promocao = $_GET['titulo_promocao'];
    $descricao = $_GET['descricao'];
    $igredientes = $_GET['igredientes'];
    $foto = $_GET['foto'];
    $valor_sem_desconto = $_GET['valor_sem_desconto'];
    $valor_com_desconto = $_GET['valor_com_desconto'];
    $validade_oferta = $_GET['validade_oferta'];
    $estoque = $_GET['estoque'];
    $cod_fornecedor = $_GET['cod_fornecedor'];
    $cod_categoria = $_GET['cod_categoria'];
    $imagem = $_GET['imagem'];
    $desconto = $_GET['desconto'];

     // INSERE OS DADOS
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=HOSTr;dbname=BANCO", "USER", "SENHA");


    if($db){

        $sql = "INSERT INTO cadastra_oferta (cod_fornecedor, cod_categoria_com, titulo_promocao, descricao, igredientes, foto, valor_sem_desconto, valor_com_desconto, desconto, validade_oferta, qtd_estoque) VALUES ('$cod_fornecedor', '$cod_categoria', '$titulo_promocao', '$descricao', '$igredientes', '$imagem', '$valor_sem_desconto', '$valor_com_desconto', '$desconto', '$validade_oferta', '$estoque')";


        $query = $db->prepare($sql);        

        $query ->execute();        

        echo json_encode(array('message'=> ' Os dados foram inseridos com sucesso. Obrigado e bem vindo!' ));
    }else{
        echo json_decode(array('message'=> ' Não foi possivel iserir os dados! Tente novamente mais tarde!' ));
    };



?>
```

Comment: qual o formato enviado pelo input?

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Comment: Valor retornado da Data : 1490842800000 Thu Mar 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O angular armazena as datas como objetos do tipo Date do JavaScript que é uma timestamp Unix (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D) e, já que você quer processar ela no PHP, você pode usar o método `date()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) para isso.

```
$validade_oferta = $_GET['validade_oferta']; // "1490842800"
$validade_date = date('Y-m-d', intval($validade_oferta)); // "2017-03-30"
```

Comment: Oi @Rômulo, registrou a data como: 1969-12-31 00:00:00

Comment: Curioso. Você está usando algum método ou tentando passar o objeto diretamente pela requisição ao PHP? Veja aqui como o objeto `Date` do input se comporta no Angular: https://plnkr.co/edit/osXfSNdz5PK1g0O6a6bN

Answer (score 1):

O banco salva a data e formato internacional ano-mes-dia 2017-01-12. Se o formulário esta sendo preenchido no formato brasileiro 12/10/2017 você deve converter a data antes de enviar para o banco.

Um modo simples de fazer isso é assim:

```
$data = implode("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$data)));
```

Outra coisa, você esta enviando os dados diretamente do cliente para o banco, isso é um pouco problemático. Pode gerar várias inconsistências e mais erros caso não seja preenchido algum campo obrigatório ou com um tipo de dado diferente.

Comment: Valor retornado da Data : 1490842800000 Thu Mar 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)

Comment: Pessoal, Muito obrigado! :)

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, você pode criar uma directive que formate para o padrão que você precisa.
Segue um outro post como referência.

[Formartar data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474555/how-to-format-a-date-using-ng-model)

Comment: Por favor, colabore com a qualidade do conteúdo da comunidade elaborando melhor sua resposta. Respostas muito curtas dificilmente serão suficientemente claras para acrescentar algo à discussão. Se sua resposta é baseada em alguma função ou característica da linguagem/ferramenta, faça a ligação com a documentação oficial ou material confiável que sustente sua resposta. Buscar perguntas semelhantes na comunidade também pode ser interessante para indicar outras abordagens do problema.